# How to ask ex-girlfriend to delete nude pictures of us that she took?

Tags: relationships, requests, mental-health

An ex-girlfriend whom I used to date around two years ago is in town. We had broken up amicably and have kept in touch somewhat. We are planning to meet this week to catch up.

Back when we were dating, one day when we were together at her flat, she took out her phone and started taking nude pictures of us. It was a bit abrupt and I wasn't sure how I felt about it but I went along with it anyway. I asked her to share the photos with me which she did. (Though, I lost my copies in a phone crash about a year ago. I didn't tell her about it.)

Two months ago she posted a suggestive cropped photo on social media which I instantly recognized as one of ours. It probably wouldn't be recognizable to others. I still felt rather violated because she didn't ask me if I was okay with the photo being shared on social media, even if intended as "art". At that time I didn't bring it up because I wasn't sure how to, after all this while - plus I wanted to avoid a conflict over the phone.

**What makes this more complicated:**

A month after she posted the photo online, she told me she is going through some intense mental health issues which periodically render her temporarily amnesiac. At those times she doesn't remember anything about her life (including who I am and that we used to date). She is struggling a lot and is in town to seek medical help. So far the doctors don't know how long it will take for her to get better.

I don't want to add to her troubles or upset her by bringing this up, but I still need to ask her to delete the nude photos of us that she has because I am not comfortable with it.

Importantly, I do not want to come across as if I'm asking this **because** of her mental health issues - that is simply not the case. I had become uncomfortable with the existence of the photos long before that.

I doubt she will do anything malicious with the photos, but it still bothers me, because I'm normally super conscious about data security and I don't want it to come and bite me in the posterior several years later.

---

**TL; DR:** Ex-girlfriend from two years ago has nude pictures, how to ask her to delete them without upsetting her, as she is also facing some intense mental health problems right now.

Answer (score 8):

A technique I've used in similar situations - not about nude pictures, but about social situations that have bothered me - is not making the whole situation about me, but as a general advice. So I would talk to her like that

> Hey, I saw in **[insert social media]** a picture of us you posted some days ago. I'm sure nobody can recognizes me but *(you can omit this part if you don't want even white little lies, to make the point clearer)* even though I'm not mad about it you should'nt post intimate pictures of someone or with someone, without their consent.

This is a general rule to everyone. My wife posted several pictures of our son with the daughter of some friends of mine, only to be told to delete them because they were against publishing anything about their daughter in social media. So you can phrase your requirement not as a personal problem of yours - or not only that - but a general rule she should be following with everybody.

**EDIT:** I'm adding this since realizing I never addressed the question of her removing the pictures she owns, like other answers do. I didn't because simply, I don't think you can ask her that - I mean, you can always *ask*, but she does not have to comply with.

You can ask her to remove the pictures from public social media, since you appear in them, but she has every right to keep them for personal use. Those pictures are a testament of your past relationship, just as any gift you gave her or any memory she has of the time you were together, and while she may be open to delete them she's on her right to keep them. The moment to object to those pictures being taken it's long past.